# Load raster layer from gpkg file

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm new with PyQGIS.
I need to load a raster layer from gpkg file, and i tried this way:

```
gpkg_raster_land_layer = "GPKG:" + path_to_gpkg + ":" + layername

r_layer = QgsRasterLayer(gpkg_raster_land_layer, layername, "gdal")
if not r_layer.isValid():
    print("Land layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(r_layer)
```

But it didn't work: `Land layer failed to load!`
I didn't understand how to proceed to load the raster, can someone help me?

Comment: Yes, it print "Land layer failed to load!"

Comment: The print statement doesn't seem to match the action, though of course you may not be able to add a non valid raster.   It would be useful probably to know why it's invalid, or what happens if just try to load add it without first doing a validity check.  That might help you go further

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the following code works to load in QGIS a raster layer contained in a geopackage:

```
s_gpkg = "path_to_gpkg"
lyr_in = QgsRasterLayer(s_gpkg, "Test", "gdal")
if lyr_in.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr_in)
```